# Service Notification Text Uses System Language

Tags: android, service, locale, android-notifications, foregroundnotification

My app support 2 languages,English and Hebrew. When I change the language to English and minimize the app, the service notification text showing in Hebrew instead of English.
Besides of the notification,the translation is working perfectly.

Now as I mentioned in the title,I figured out that its happening because my system language is Hebrew.

How can I overcome this issue?

Thank you!

EDIT:

Change Language Button (Only MainActivity,From popup menu) -

```kotlin
popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menu_item) {
        int itemId = menu_item.getItemId();
        if (itemId == R.id.English) {
            changeLang(getApplicationContext(), "en");
            getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR);

            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
        } else if (itemId == R.id.Hebrew) {
            changeLang(getApplicationContext(), "iw");
            getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);

            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
        }
        return true;
    }
});

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = 
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(newBase);
    LANG_CURRENT = preferences.getString("Language", "en");

    super.attachBaseContext(MyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase, LANG_CURRENT));
}

public void changeLang(Context context, String lang) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString("Language", lang);
    editor.apply();
}
```

Service onCreate -

```kotlin
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    if (MainActivity.LANG_CURRENT.equals("en")) {
        changeLang(getApplicationContext(),"en");
        Lang = "en";
    } else {
        changeLang(getApplicationContext(),"iw");
        Lang = "iw";
    }
}
```

Service Notification -

```kotlin
NotificationCompat.Action action2 = new NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.ic_cancel, getString(R.string.stop), servicePendingIntent);

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
    .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.launch))
    .addAction(action)
    .addAction(action2)
    .setColor(getColor(R.color.foreGroundBackgroundColor))
    .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
    .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.applogo)
    .build();

startForeground(2, notification);
```

The translation is working perfectly for all the activities except for the service notification..

**THE SOLUTION THANKS TO @Eyosiyas -**

Service Activity -

In onStartCommand I did this -

```kotlin
if (MainActivity.LANG_CURRENT.equals("en")) {
    Locale locale = new Locale("en");
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Resources resources = this.getResources();
    Configuration config = resources.getConfiguration();
    config.setLocale(locale);
    resources.updateConfiguration(config, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
} else {
    Locale locale = new Locale("iw");
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Resources resources = this.getResources();
    Configuration config = resources.getConfiguration();
    config.setLocale(locale);
    resources.updateConfiguration(config, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

Comment: Post some code that we can look at.

Comment: @Eyosiyas Thank you for your reply,code added.

Comment: Where is the serice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**onCreate** method of your service.
Make the necessary adjustments if required.

```
Locale locale = new Locale(language);
Locale.setDefault(locale);

Resources resources = context.getResources();

Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
configuration.locale = locale;
resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
```

Optimized code for **onStartCommand**

```
Locale locale;
if (MainActivity.LANG_CURRENT.equals("en"))
    locale = new Locale("en");
else
    locale = new Locale("iw");

Locale.setDefault(locale);
Resources resources = this.getResources();
Configuration config = resources.getConfiguration();
config.setLocale(locale);
resources.updateConfiguration(config, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
```

Comment: First of all thank you,Its working!
 BUT every time I change the language through the button,the activity restarts and all the strings are change perfectly except the notification ,only when I restart the app completely ,the notification finally change.

How can I do it without restart the app ?
Thanks again !

Comment: Restart the service.

Comment: The service isn't working yet ,and still, when the service is running for the first time after changing the language its not changing,only when I restart the app

Comment: Move the language logic from onCreate to onStartCommand.

Answer (score 0):

**This solution will only work if you have pre-defined notifications String.**
like `String.format("Your order id %s has been processed!",orderId);`

In you service, while binding notification meta-data, let service access current selected language. According to the language pass the format string to a separate method which returns translated Title & Message

Comment: Thanks for reply,I pre-defined my notification string using the translated string xml.
I call it like this:

getString(R.string.launch)